# Is there any major differences between Adobe AIR over Titanium

Tags: air, titanium

at first i thought with Titanium, i can develop for Mobile and Desktop over AIR on Desktop only, but a quick look at the [AIR Site](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/), i guess i am wrong.

> Benefit from a consistent, flexible,
>   and visual development environment for
>   applications on multiple platforms and
>   devices such as smartphones,
>   **smartbooks, tablets, netbooks**, and
>   PCs.

so my question is are there any major differences of titanium over air that i shld be aware of?

if no, i guess now air maybe better documented and has the backing of a more recognized company? after working with titanium desktop for a while i felt abit helpless and the docs are not really helping much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of subtle differences, of course, and there are advantages and disadvantages to working in either, but the largest difference is that Titanium can produce apps for the iPhone/iPad, and AIR can't (well, at least not conveniently).

AIR can produce iPhone apps that you can deploy using the ad-hoc provisioning, but you can't distribute via the app store.

Comment: -1 because you can distribute adobe air app in App Store like any other native iOS app. We have a app called Youppie for LIVE STREAM, and Adobe Air app was the best fit for our purposes, because the app can connect with a streaming server (FMS).

Comment: @rizidoro: You -1 an answer from 2 years ago, which was true at the time?

Answer (score 0):

I've got desktop apps on both and am making a mobile app right now. Titanium desktop will cut your dev time to 1/3 of the time you'll take jumping through AIRs various sandboxes and security measures. Best yet, the code I wrote for my Ti desktop app is all javascript with about 3 Ti API calls and can be taken anywhere. The AIR app is all mangled by the wild structure you have to use with AIR apps and 1 million api calls.

The downside to Ti desktop is the API isn't as fully featured, and the Ti team pushes 4 times as many updates for the mobile API as the desktop API. Also, you won't be able to port your app from desktop to mobile easily as they are two different structures and APIs.

That said, developing for iPhone and Android on Ti is the same exact process and that won't happen on AIR.

Lots to weigh, but for my money it's Ti over AIR.

Hope this helps.